# Foxpro soap connection to https

Tags: soap, foxpro

I have found and run the code snipped below, if this was a https url would it still work?

```
loSoap = CREATEOBJECT("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")

loSoap.MSSoapInit("http://www.foxcentral.net/foxcentral.wsdl")

lcXML =  loSoap.GetProviders()

? lcXml

XMLTOCURSOR(lcXML,"xproviders",0)

BROWSE

RELEASE loSoap
```

Has anyone a simple example running a method on a https connection in foxpro?

Thank you

Comment: Haven't tried, but why not? I can't see anything bad with the given sample. Besides, I would be wary to use a webservice NOT served over a secured connection.

Answer (score -1):

No it wouldn't work because how are you supplying authentication?

Comment: Https doesn't implies any kind of authentication. Only secures the transport layer. Also, since it ultimately relies on the CryptoApi, the certificate validation is also handled by Windows.